# Pandas - add multiple values to row inside while loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a dataframe inside a while loop that needs to be updated based on the simulation time. Here's an example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

n = 0
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B'])

while n < 10:
  df = df.append({'A': random.uniform(0, 1), 'B': random.uniform(0, 1)}, 
                 ignore_index=True)
  df = df.append({'A': random.uniform(0, 1), 'B': random.uniform(0, 1)}, 
                 ignore_index=True)

  df['New Column'] = n

  print('This value should be added to the new rows only ' + str(n))
  n += 1
  print(df)
```

This results in the **entire** new column being updated at once, which is undesired in my case. Here are the first three prints:

```
This value should be added to the new rows only 0
          A         B  New Column
0  0.242312  0.369978           0
1  0.709112  0.650794           0
This value should be added to the new rows only 1
          A         B  New Column
0  0.242312  0.369978           1    <- should have been 0
1  0.709112  0.650794           1    <- should have been 0
2  0.293787  0.229019           1
3  0.828184  0.917984           1
This value should be added to the new rows only 2
          A         B  New Column
0  0.242312  0.369978           2    <- should have been 0
1  0.709112  0.650794           2    <- should have been 0
2  0.293787  0.229019           2    <- should have been 1
3  0.828184  0.917984           2    <- should have been 1
4  0.644289  0.589050           2
5  0.371361  0.759865           2
```

Can I do this in one operation or I need to copy to another dataframe and then append that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

n = 0
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'New Column'])

while n < 10:
  df = df.append({'A': random.uniform(0, 1), 'B': random.uniform(0, 1), 'New Column': n}, 
                 ignore_index=True)
  df = df.append({'A': random.uniform(0, 1), 'B': random.uniform(0, 1), 'New Column': n}, 
                 ignore_index=True)

  print('This value should be added to the new rows only ' + str(n))
  n += 1
  print(df)
```

Simply just have a `New Column` from the beginning, and then add the value just like you do with `A` and `B` inside the `append`, I am making `New Column` also in the same `append`s.

Your code doesn't work since you're modifying *all* values on every loop occasion, when you need it for the appended dataframe, which is what I'm doing.